# Can't upload file in java spring boot to the tomcat hosting server, always show access denined for the given file upload path in fedora

Tags: java, linux, spring, file-upload, tomcat7

i need the help if i have a chance. I wasn't familiar for tomcat for a long time , deploying the java war file .Now i'm getting the problem "access denied for the file :... " which always log on hosting server . The main point is that i can't upload to the hosting server and i always get an Exception "access denied " for that part

```
String path=System.getProperty("user.home")+"/UploadFiles/";

try {
        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

        Path path = Paths.get(p+ "img.jpg");

        Files.write(path, bytes);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your Tomcat process can write to wherever `path` is pointing. Most likely it's a permission issue, the JVM process can't write to `[...]/UploadFiles/` directory.